# Using the variable in a for loop

Tags: google-apps-script

This is mostly a concept question, and I don't know how to accomplish this if it is possible. Can I declare the variable y before the loop like this?

```
var y = 1;
for (var y; y < 4; y++)
```

Comment: Why shouldn't you be able to declare it before the loop? Did you try? What happened? What happened when you printed the variable value after the loop? Does your code work as is? If not, why not? If yes, what is the difference between the y`variables outside and inside the loop?

Comment: But why you want to do so ? If you want a global variable simply declare it as global and assign the value like y=1 with the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

HAHA silly me you can, it looks like this.

var y = 1;

for(y; y < 4; y++){

}